# output from calcOpticalFlowPyrLK function in openCV

Tags: c++, opencv

Im new to openCV and image processing I am trying to find moving objects using optical flow (Lucas-Kanade method) by comparing two saved images on disk which are frames from a camera.

The part of code I am asking about is:

```
Mat img = imread("t_mono1.JPG", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);//read the image

Mat img2 = imread("t_mono2.JPG", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);//read the 2nd image 

Mat pts;
Mat pts2;
Mat stat;
Mat err; 

goodFeaturesToTrack(img,pts,100,0.01,0.01);//extract features to track

calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(img,img2,pts,pts2,stat,err);//optical flow

cout<<" "<<pts.cols<<"\n"<<pts.rows<<"\n";`
```

I am getting that the size of pts is 100 by 1. I suppose it should have been 100 by 2 since the pixels have x and y coordinates. Further, when I used for loops to display the contents of the arrays the pts array was all zeros and all arrays were one dimensional.

I have seen this question:
[OpenCV's calcOpticalFlowPyrLK throws exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623128/opencvs-calcopticalflowpyrlk-throws-exception)

I tried using vectors as he did but I get an error when building it says cannot convert between different data types. I am using VS2008 with openCV2.4.11

I would like to get the (x,y) coordinates of features in the first and second images and the error but all the arrays passed to calcOpticalFlowPyrLK were one dimensional and I don't understand how can this be?

Comment: Please carefully read the comments of the refered Question the problem was that. stat and err had the wrong type. I your case try std::vector<cv::Point2f> pts, pts2  ... std::vector<uchar> stat and std::vector<float> err